# get and save path to php.ini file

Tags: path, php, php-ini

Is it possible to get the path to the php.ini file with a php script and save this path to a variable? I know I can call phpinfo() to find out the path, but it prints a lot of info and I only need the path to php.ini file and no output at all. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you need this for? There may be snags in the process, e.g. PHP showing a wrong path if no ini file is present at all.

Comment: @Pekka I need this to present in a special information block in the system I am working on. The system is used by different clients on different servers, so the path may vary. Snags do not frighten me)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, there are two functions related to what you would like to do. The first one is exactly what you're looking for, the second one shows the bigger picture that there can be more than one ini file:

1. [`php_ini_loaded_file`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) - Retrieve a path to the loaded php.ini file.
2. [`php_ini_scanned_files`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php) - Return a list of .ini files parsed from the additional ini dir.

Next to that, mind the gap with [*.user.ini files*](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php), they don't show up in `php_ini_scanned_files` nor `phpinfo`.

Comment: Wow, I never knew these functions existed... Makes life a lot easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You could exec("php -i | grep php.ini"), and grab that output. 
Or you could use outputbuffering (ob_start()), run phpinfo(), get the contents of the outputbuffer (ob_get_contents()) and search trough that (preg_match) to find the php.ini file...

Answer (score 0):

This works on the command line, might also work for the CGI:

```
ob_start(); phpinfo();
if ( preg_match( '#>(.+)/php.ini#', ob_get_clean(), $matches ) ) {
    echo 'php.ini location: ' . trim( $matches[1] ) . '/php.ini';
}
```